# failing pjsua python module

Tags: python, sip, pjsip

I try to use pjsua module for Python on Ubuntu 16.04.
When I try to call AccountConfig, it will return with following error message:

```
>>> import pjsua
>>> t=pjsua.AccountConfig()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pjsua.py", line 802, in __init__
    self._cvt_from_pjsua(default)
  File "pjsua.py", line 859, in _cvt_from_pjsua
    for cred in cfg.cred_info:
MemoryError
```

Compiled pjsip with following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libpjsua2
wget http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.7.2/pjproject-2.7.2.tar.bz2
sudo rm -fr pjproject-2.7.2
tar -xf pjproject-2.7.2.tar.bz2 && cd pjproject-2.7.2/
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
./configure --enable-shared  --disable-sound  && make dep && make
cd pjsip-apps/src/python/
sudo python setup.py install
```

I would appreciate any idea, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile with following solved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev libpjsua2 libssl-dev libasound2-dev
wget http://www.pjsip.org/release/2.7.2/pjproject-2.7.2.tar.bz2
tar -xf pjproject-2.7.2.tar.bz2 && cd pjproject-2.7.2/
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
./configure && make dep && make
cd pjsip-apps/src/python/
sudo python setup.py install
```